# Caching on Method like MVC's OutputCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

Is it possible to implement an ASP.NET MVC's [OutputCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute on a non-controller method?

I want to implement it in my Services layer of my application that returns a `relatively constant` result, but I want to avoid writing code for every single method to check for existing item in cache, and insert if it doesn't exists, etc.

I would prefer OutputCache attribute style, where I would just apply an attribute to the method and specify an expiring timing and 'vary by params'.

Would that be possible?

Comment: If you use a DI framework there is a good chance such support is already built in or readily available. I.e. check out how it can be done with Unity - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec5. Be careful if you need to support async methods - older versions / libraries may not properly handle async methods.

Comment: I'm using Ninject at the moment, but I have no idea what keyword(s) I should be searching for.

Comment: Generally it is called "interception" - http://www.bing.com/search?q=ninject+interception+caching seem to give good links.